# ITextSharp is not rendering the albpabets lists in the PDF

Tags: pdf, itext, rendering

itext html to pdf is not printing as a,b,c format in c#
when I convert the html to pdf the html format  is not working as the alphabets format , it shows only numbers as 1,2,3. Please give any instruction to make this happen.

I tried  it is not working as expected